# Modify properties of an element but only when it's inside other in CSS

Tags: css, html, article

I have a page structure which looks like:

```
<article><p>Title</p></article>
```

I'd like to modify the `p` only when it's inside the `<article>`. I tried

```
article > p {
  font: 15px;
}
```

And:

```
article p {
  font: 15px;
}
```

But neither of them work :(
How shall I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selectors are correct. The problem is that when you use the [shorthand `font` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand), the minimum you can specify is the `font-size` and `font-family`:

```
article p {
    font: 15px Arial;
}
```

Note that your second example uses the child selector, which I don't believe is supported in IE6, so I'd recommend using the first format.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/K3A9K/5/) of the above.